# WPF Shaped Button - Visaul Studio/Blend

Tags: c#, wpf

I recently started learning WPF and I ran into a small problem. I am trying to create a basic button shape (Transparent) that would fit my style that I made in Photoshop.

Here is the shape (Its like a box with a triangle on each side).
http://prntscr.com/g3esel

If its easier to do it in Blend and implement it into visual then Id love to know how.

BUTTON STYLE:

```
        <Style x:Key="Clicky" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid Height="74" Width="284" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                <Setter Property="Button.Opacity" Value="10" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend doing it in blend. But before we go any further we don't know what you question really is. If you have any trouble with any code related stuff. Then please ask away. But do not expect us to do your work.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I dont know how to use Blend so thats another Issue...

Comment: Blend is pretty easy to use but you can do the same thing in Visual Studio. It's preferences really. It does seem that you are lucky and someone gave you an example on how to do your thing. However I would first try to learn the language more and experiment with these things yourself. We love to help but we also expect you to have done enough research. The community punishes questions like the fairly hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates) for the `Button`. This can be done both in Blend and Visual Studio. I did it in VS2015.
Here is your code:

But, for the future, try to do [some work yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting the question. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Button Height="52" Opacity="0.8">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                            <GradientStop Color="#053755" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#053755" Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#061F31" Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#061F31" Offset="1.0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Margin="-1,0" Grid.Column="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="M13,0 0,25 0,27 13,52 13,52" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="13" Stretch="Fill" ClipToBounds="True"/>
                                <Path Grid.Column="2" Data="M0,0 13,25 13,27 0,52" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="13" Stretch="Fill" ClipToBounds="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I did do some research before posting here, but didnt manage to find something helpful.

Comment: In regards to the button, I have created a simple temple for it that would change the cursor when the mouse it over it and change the opacity. For some reason the opacity doesnt work... (Added the code to the post)

Comment: Maximum Opacity value is 1. Also if you need to change any property using triggers, you need to avoid setting this property in button local value (This link explains why - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). Remove the local opacity value (Opacity="0.8") and add the setter to the style.(<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>)

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing would really help me. If I have 4 buttons on my page and in the code behind I want to access them in a loop, can that be done by putting them in an array of somesort?

Comment: You could give the Grid an id, make a function that looks for the id and then ask for all the button objects in there i suppose. But I don't know what you want to accomplish

Comment: You should not access your buttons from code-behind in the first place. Try to use MVVM pattern and it will make your life easier. @Totumus Maximus is right. Implementation depends on what you want to accomplish.